# Getting Specific Value Of Registry Key in CMD

Tags: cmd, registry

I am trying to list all the programs installed via cmd and i am using registry key for this purpose. `RegistryKey` is as follows

```
REG QUERY HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall /s > \"C:\Users\Kosmo\Final.txt"
```

it lists saves the list in a file as following

[image]

As it lists all the software complete information but what can i do to have only few of the properties e.g only `DispalyName` or Publisher etc ?

What would be the syntax for the key then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
REG QUERY HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall /s | findstr /L "DisplayName Publisher"> \"C:\Users\Kosmo\Final.txt"
```

add `/i` to `/L` (ie `/L /i`) if you want case-insensitive.

Comment: Won't that filter out tree node names?

Comment: AFAICS, that's what is required. Well, OK - if the data contains those strings, then it'll let those through, too. Could be overcome with `/c:"DisplayName   REG_" /c:"Publisher   REG_"` if required. (number of spaces to match the number in the data line) or possibly `/R` in place of `/L` and `/c:"DisplayName *REG_" /c:"Publisher *REG_"